# Vuex state item is always empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vuex and realy like it. However I've got a weird problem. I've got a module called `filters` it looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default {
    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        filters: [{ key: 'page', value: 1 }],
        criterias: [
            {
                name: " LIFE",
                filter: "LIFE",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " FACILITIES",
                filter: "FACILITIES",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " WIFI",
                filter: "WIFI",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " FUN FOR KIDS",
                filter: "FUN_FOR_KIDS",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " FUN FOR ADULTS",
                filter: "FUN_FOR_ADULTS",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " COSTS",
                filter: "COSTS",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " WATER QUALITY",
                filter: "WATER_QUALITY",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: "⛵ SAIL BOAT FRIENDLY",
                filter: "SAIL_BOAT_FRIENDLY",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: "️ MOTOR BOAT FRIENDLY",
                filter: "MOTOR_BOAT_FRIENDLY",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " SPANISH SPEAKING",
                filter: "SPANISH_SPEAKING",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " RESTAURANTS",
                filter: "RESTAURANTS",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: "✌️ PEACE",
                filter: "PEACE",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: "️ PARKING SPOTS (CAR)",
                filter: "PARKING_SPOTS",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: " ENGLISH SPEAKING",
                filter: "ENGLISH_SPEAKING",
                active: false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**(I import this module in my main.js file)**

When I try to get the `criterias` from this `module` in a custom component:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                criterias: []
            }
        },

        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                criteriasVuex: state => state.filters.criterias
            })
        },

        created() {
            this.criterias = this.criteriasVuex.slice(0, 7);
        }
    }
</script>
```

`Criterias` is always empty! When I look in `vue-devtools` no `criterias` are visible in my component or `vuex state`!!! How is this possible?

The weird thing is that `filters` on the `state` is not empty! I can see that in `vue-devtools`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work with the code you have shown (see sample [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/624vly6613)), so likely the problem is in the way the filter module is added to the store.

Here is a store that works

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

import filters from "./filtersModule";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const modules = {
  filters
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    import {mapState} from 'vuex'
    export default {

        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                criterias
            })
        },
    }
</script>
```

Should bring you further. 'state.filters.criterias' won't work because:

1. You're in the MapState function, thus the "state" namespace needs to be omitted.
2. criterias is not a subobject of filters.

Comment: Thanks for helping! The module is called `filters` that's why I use `filters.criterias` so what should it then be? (example you gave does not work)

Comment: Yes, but does not work. What on earth is going on here!!